# Move files after one hour

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move log files which are created one hour earlier. It is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

```
$Path = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Old\*"
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$Hours = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include "*.txt" | ForEach-Object {(Get-Date $_.CreationTime).Hour} | Sort-Object | Get-Unique 
for ($Hour = 0; $Hour -lt 24; $Hour++) 
{
    if ($Hour -in $Hours)
    { 
        Write-Host "There's at least one file for $Hour o'clock for $Date." -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
    else
    { 
        Write-Host "There's no file present for $Hour o'clock for $Date." -ForegroundColor Red 
    }
}
move-item -destination "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\New\"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is complicated for the task. Here is code for searching file that older than one hour and moving it to your folder.

```
Clear-Host
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\Old\*.txt"
foreach($item in $fileList) {
    $item.FullName
    if((New-TimeSpan -Start $($item.CreationTime) -End $(Get-Date)).TotalHours -gt 1) {
        Move-Item -Path $item -Destination "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\New\"
    }
}
```