# Move each file after two hours to another folder using VBA

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

Through VBA code I move most recent files (after 10 files) to another folder.

I would like, if any file is saved/comes in Source folder, that it should move after two hours to Destination folder.

E.g. A file is saved/comes in Source folder at 10:00 AM, it should move to Destination at 12:00 PM (i.e. after 2 hours).

Similarly if another file was saved at 10:10 AM, it should move to Destination folder at 12:10 PM (after two hours) and so on.

This means for each file, check the computer time and move after two hours.
If there are no files in the folder check every three to five minutes.

Users save numerous files with different file names and formats (specifically .txt .xml and .pdf).

Current code:

```vb
Sub MostRecentFyles_1062357()
Dim oFSO As Object, oFSOFolder As Object, oFSOFile As Object
Dim sFilePath As String, sFilePath2 As String
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i As Long, kounter As Long
i = 1
kounter = 0
sFilePath = "E:\Source\"
sFilePath2 = "E:\Destination\"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFSOFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFilePath)
kounter = oFSOFolder.Files.Count
If kounter < 11 Then Exit Sub
ReDim arr(1 To kounter, 1 To 2)
For Each oFSOFile In oFSOFolder.Files
    arr(i, 1) = oFSOFile.Name
    arr(i, 2) = FileDateTime(oFSOFile)
    i = i + 1
Next oFSOFile
arr = SortArrayZtoA(arr)

For i = 5 To UBound(arr)
    oFSO.movefile Source:=sFilePath & arr(i, 1), Destination:=sFilePath2 & arr(i, 1)
Next i
Set oFSOFile = Nothing
Set oFSOFolder = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
Erase arr
End Sub

Function SortArrayZtoA(arr As Variant)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Dim Temp
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)

        If CDate(arr(i, 2)) < CDate(arr(j, 2)) Then 'change less than symbol to greater than to sort A to Z

            For n = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                Temp = arr(j, n)
                arr(j, n) = arr(i, n)
                arr(i, n) = Temp
            Next n
        End If
    Next j
Next i
SortArrayZtoA = arr
End Function
```

Comment: What is your question: How to move a file? How to check if a file is 2h old? How to trigger code all *n* minutes?

Comment: The file will come into the Source folder after some other processes running,

Comment: The file can be moved via Filesystemobject or any other process but this is where i need help that each file should be moved after every 2 hours,

Comment: Is it possible if there is any possibility where VBA code reads itself the computer time whenever the files comes into the Source folder and then start the timer for 2 hours. I know it is vague but i wish if there is any help

Comment: there is some similar type of code available at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950493/move-files-after-one-hour but i need the help in VBA as rest of my processes are in VBA

Comment: If it requires to write the File names in excel sheet i can write it so that the code can read the file name from Excel but first name of each file are same and last part are different always (dates)

Comment: The complication is that every file comes in the source folder at different time and it should be moved after every 2 hours (120 minutes) if i run such type of monitors or schedulers it will move all the files from source folder and the concept of 2 hours delay of movement will not be met

Comment: There are more than 100 files i expect in source folder everyday,  is there any possibility that if anyone can write a code for me in which the code will execute one file at a time and add a timer in it, and we can add a loop in the end so that after executing one file it can move to read the second file or something like this

Comment: Dear @KJ i am afraid i am not able to write a code at all, if you could please help and write a complete code for me in VBA i shall remain thankful

Comment: ok let me try to do it. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try to have the code to be run on a timer every x minutes. Check out Do Events concerning other running code, or let the timercode run from a seperate workbook or powershell/vbs code.